# How to change canvas resolution according to uploaded image using intput?

Tags: html, css

I have a canvas in my HTML code and and input tag to upload only a single image of any type.
I want to change the width and height of the canvas matching the width and height of the image that is input through the input tag but frankly I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'll need to listen to the `onchange` event of the input, create a js Image element and attach an `onload` callback function and then set the src attribute of the image element. On the onload callback you can get the intrinsic height and width of the image and update the canvas. Something like...

```
input.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  const img = document.createElement('IMG')
  img.onload = function(ev) {
    let width = ev.target.naturalWidth
    let height = ev.target.naturalHeight
    myCanvas.width = width
    myCanvas.height = height
  }

  img.src = e.target.files[0].path // I don't remember this exact line though
})
```